# Map load on Ajax calling in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

Map is not loading in my popup window.
view/test.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".popup_property").click(function(e){ //on add input button click
     var id = $(this).attr('href'); 
        $.post( "<?php echo base_url()?>admin/host/viewproperty/"+id , function( data ) {
  $( ".popupview1" ).html( data );
});

  });     
});
    </script>
```

Controller file:

host.php controller file  function viewProperty

```
function viewProperty()
    {
 .....
        $hostPreviewHtml = '<div id="map"  class="pagescroll col-xs-12 row">
                    <div style="height: 250px;
               " id="mapview"></div>                
                    </div>

                    </div></div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var map;
    var marker;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.708006,-119.5559652)
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function initialize(){
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapview"), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: myLatlng,
    draggable: true 
    }); 
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

    </script>
    ';
        echo $hostPreviewHtml;
        }
```

No console error . but map is not loading in popup window. please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't set the Maps JS script source.

You can check out the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) page of the Maps JS API and see if there are other items still missing from your implementation.

Happy coding!